# How to change the date format in datepiker material is angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

How to change the date format in datepiker material is angular, data is sent to the back in full format and you need 01/01/2020 - through a dot

Answer (score 0):

### In your component

```
import { CustomDataAdapter } from 'path.........';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-selector',
  templateUrl: './some-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-selector.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDataAdapter}
  ],
})
```

### Custom Date Adapter

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeDateAdapter } from "@angular/material/core";

@Injectable()
export class CustomDataAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        if ( displayFormat['year'] == "numeric" && displayFormat['month'] == "numeric" && displayFormat['day'] == "numeric" ){
            const seperator = ".";
            return `${date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}${seperator}${(date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}${seperator}${date.getFullYear()}`;
        }
        return super.format(date, displayFormat);
    }
}
```